# iOS: UICollectionViewCell ContentView subview always count One

Tags: ios, uicollectionviewcell, subview

How to add dynamic view inside `UICollectionViewCell` but when I scroll `UICollectionView` the view has remove and add last index of cell.
Now I have add view on all Appear cell.

Comment: Please elaborate & add some code

Comment: @VipinSaini please add your code

Comment: on screen green color view I have add as subview and red color for collectionViewCell. See This Link for Detail...    https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PRJ5g3DvD7MRmc4gkEhz7r0vsSF2Wm2HCq07epknz_4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be adding/removing subviews at `cellForItemAtIndexPath()`.

That is to say, you should probably `removeAllSubviews()` and then `cell.addSubview(yourSubview)` every time.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this

```
cell.contentView.removeAllSubviews()
cell.contentView.addSubview(yourSubview)
```

May this help u 
let me know if it works.